# How to view Cauchy convergence in complete function spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I am confused, the text am reading says that in function space $L$ with its respective norm (say for example the Euclidien $L^2$ norm), a Cauchy sequence $\textbf{x}_n \in l$ is s.t. $\|\textbf{x}_n-\textbf{x}_m\| < \epsilon$, for all $n,m > N$, for any $\epsilon > 0$.

But what if we have the sequence (similar to typewriter sequence).

$$
x_1 = I_{(0,1/2]} \quad x_2=I_{(1/2,1]} \quad x_3 = I_{(0,1/4]} \quad x_4=I_{(1/4,1/2]}  \quad x_5 = I_{(1/2,3/4]}...
$$

In this case, given the norm, we have that the sequence above converges in the norm and should meet the definition of Cauchy (as per my text), but it does not converge pointwise... this is a common example in probability for a sequence that converges in the norm but does not converge almost everywhere (or pointwise)

Does this mean that there can be Cauchy sequences in a complete normed sequence space that do not converge pointwise?

Comment: but the text am reading says that the sequence space can also be viewed as a function space $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: What space does your sequence $x_1 = I_{(0, 1/2]}$, etc. belong to?  What is the norm on that space?  This has to be clearly specified.  (By the way: the concept of "Cauchy in norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$" and "convergence in norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$" depends on the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ you choose.  The concept of "pointwise convergence," on the other hand, only makes sense for spaces of functions, and is separate from the two concepts mentioned in the prior sentence.)

Comment: okay, i edited my query, let's say the norm it's the euclidian norm $||.||$, and it's a function space

Comment: A function space?  Which function space?  Is it one of the Holder spaces, or Sobolev spaces, or what?  There are several different function spaces.  And the "absolute value norm" is a norm on the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers; it's not a norm on any function space.  (Did you mean the supremum norm?)

Comment: Okay, I edited my query again, it's the $L^{p=2}$ space (Holder space), and the norm should be that for $L^2[0,1]$

Comment: Yes, the typewriter sequence is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the $L^2$ norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^2}$.  Since $L^2[0,1]$ is complete with respect to $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^2}$, the typewriter sequence converges with respect to $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^2}$.  But the typewriter sequence does not converge pointwise.  (Therefore, it also does not converge uniformly, meaning that it does not converge with respect to the supremum norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{C^0}$.)  By the way, $L^2$ is not a Holder space.  The Holder spaces are $C^{k,\alpha}$.

Comment: L2 convergence is, somewhat imprecisely, about whether area under the difference curve converges to zero, whereas pointwise convergence is about function values, which should feel inherently different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typewriter sequence

- is Cauchy with respect to $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^2}$;
- converges with respect to $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^2}$;

but it

- does not converge pointwise;
- is not Cauchy with respect to the supremum norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{C^0}$;
- does not converge with respect to the supremum norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{C^0}$.

The spaces $L^p[0,1]$ are simply called $L^p$ spaces.  The Holder spaces refer to $C^{k,\alpha}$, which are different.  The Sobolev spaces refer to $W^{k,p}$, which are also different.

Answer (score 2):

The point here is that you are confusing what it means to converge in an abstract normed vector space. While it's true that in this case the vectors are themselves functions, it is not necessarily true that convergence in this space is equivalent to pointwise convergence. You can have a convergent sequence of functions which do NOT converge pointwise, depending on which norm you select.